# how to convert odoo8 fields to odoo11

Tags: python, odoo-10, odoo-11

how to convert and migrate **odoo8** fields to **odoo11**.

Please give me solution

**python code odoo8:**

```
_columns = {
        'name' : fields.char('Name', 64, required=True),
        'code' : fields.char('Code', 9, required=True),
        'description' : fields.text('Description'),
        'active': fields.boolean('Active', help="If the active field is set to False, it will allow you to hide the record without removing it."),
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `_columns` anymore, and the field types start now with capital letters.

```
name = fields.Char(
    string='Name',
    size=64,
    required=True,
)
code = fields.Char(
    string='Code',
    size=9,
    required=True
)
description = fields.Text(
    string='Description',
)
active = fields.Boolean(
    string='Active',
    help='If the active field is set to False, it will allow you to hide the '
         'record without removing it.'
)
```

Comment: I want to  odoo 8 all fields convert to odoo10. Any script code

Comment: Just use the replace functionality of your code editor

Comment: @Sankar guru, people work and earn money doing that kind of migrations, I guess nobody is helping you free. I thought you were trying to do it by yourself. Use regular expressions in your script, if finally you do it by yourself.

Comment: @forvas, I will try. Thank you!